# Jquery UI Modal anonymous function callback to open dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to create a function like function(url,class) to create a modal,load in a page and then display it. however this function is dynamically called from reflection of method names in a SignalR hub, each time it opens up all modals, I need to be able to pass in a div ID unique to open up just the modal created in that instance, I have spent a while on this and have the below but can't get it to work... Please help!!!!

I think it needs to be some kind of anonymous callback, I have also messed about with eval() to no avail, thoughts?

So   modalGo('/x.html','divid')

would create a modal open only for the specific variable created div?

```
function modalGo(url,x) {
var $dialog = $('<div id ="' + x + '></div>').load(url).dialog({
autoOpen: false,
modal: true,
height: 625,
width: 500,
title: "",
zIndex: 190000
}, function() {
$(document.getElementById(x)).dialog('open');
});
}
```

Comment: Can't you just set `autoOpen` to true?

Comment: What event handle the anonymous function? You want to aopen dialog when you call modalGo or after? Is your $dialog appended to body

Comment: I want the anon function to fire after  the dialog is declared and loaded inner html.

Answer (score 1):

i think you must append the div dialog

http://jsfiddle.net/NdN2L/

```
$(function(){


function modalGo(url,x) {
var dialog = $('<div>Ciao compa</div>');
$('#bibi').append(dialog);
dialog.dialog({
autoOpen: true,
modal: true,
height: 625,
width: 500,
title: "",
zIndex: 190000
}).show();
}

modalGo('http://www.pippo.com','test');

});
```

Comment: Thank you, I think I was over thinking this, :)

Comment: How do I call .load on this solution though:

var dialog = $('<div></div>').load(url);

does not want to work

Comment: Try with this http://jsfiddle.net/fXjrx/ you must load a page in the same origin and on the dialog div